# Getting the numbers of monitors as present in Screen Resolution window

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, screens

I need to find a way to get the correct ID's of the connected screens that will be equal to the numbers present in the Windows 7 or 8 Screen Resolution window.

I tried to use WMI query and calling Win32 API functions and still i cant get the correct numbers.
The DeviceName (like '\.\DISPLAY4') has nothing to do with screen number 4 as shown in the Screen Resolution window.

The same problem (without a solution) has been posted in 2010 in this url:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/668e3cf9-4e00-4b40-a6f8-c7d2fc1afd39/how-can-i-retrieve-monitor-information?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Microsoft's answer was that:
"There is not a supported way to figour out the IDs that you referred to programmatically. It was never a design goal to provide a way for applications to label monitors with the same IDs that the screen resolution control panel uses.".

Maybe someone has an idea how it still could be possible?

Comment: are you doing this in C# or C++?

Comment: hi, i am doing this in c#

Comment: The response from Microsoft suggests that it's arbitrary, so why does it matter? Just assign your own numbers.

Comment: Microsoft's answer is quite clear